# How to implement spring oauth2 custom flow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

We have a oath2 authentication and authorization server. In this server we implement custom flow of authentication. Steps are:

1- handshake (mobile number)

2- send otp to mobile number

3- verify otp (in this step we register user with mobile number)

4- send token (for access other services)

5- refresh token

At now, we have a client application that users register and use services from this application. We want to integrate with spring oauth2. Is there any way in spring that to implement this authentication flow in client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this sample [spring-custom-token-auth](https://github.com/rainu/spring-custom-token-auth), We can create custom authentication scenario in spring security.